# Is it correct to name "Feedback form" to any html form which could be filled by website visitor?

Tags: html, terminology

Maybe this question should be asked on English Language forum, however the people who is far from web development could not answer this question.

Suppose there is "Contact Us" form or "Ask question" form on some website. Is it correct to call it "Feedback form"?

This question is important because file names, variables names, classes names etc. related with html form depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

See [the dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/feedback):

> Information about reactions to a product, a person's performance of a task, etc. which is used as a basis for improvement

A contact form is a form used to let the user send you information about an arbitrary topic of their choice. It is not specifically to get their feedback.

A form allowing the user to ask a question is not asking for their feedback.

If all forms were feedback forms, then there would be no reason to use the word "feedback" to distinguish them from other forms.

Answer (score -1):

I appreciate, you come up with a good idea indeed!! You can give the name as feedback form and it doesn't matter if and only your form validation is perfect and works properly.